# Dishwasher plumbing

Tags: plumbing

I am remodeling my kitchen and have to make some changes to supply lines.
The existing dishwasher connection- shown below seems to have a weird
coupling. Is there a reason for doing this? Can I get rid of the 3/4 inch
stub?
[image]

Comment: That looks like what happens when you have to finish a job and you are out of 1/2" pipe but have 3/4 and reducers.  You can safely remove it.

Comment: haha thank you !

Comment: [Wide lanes.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPiW6foOhCw)

Comment: If it's not too much trouble to empty the pipe, I'd take out that dumb stop too and put in a nice new quarter-turn style.

Comment: @RMDman answers down there! ;)

Comment: @ FreeMan...............Free WIll.................